# Is it possible to tell whether a compiled Android app is using a WebView?

Tags: android

For instance, I want to know what part of the Netflix android app is implemented using a WebView, because I'd like to do something similar (the way the rows and columns of movie thumbnails scroll horizontally and vertically) and want to know if it is even possible using a WebView.

One thing I have done is turned on some of the developer tools on my device, such as the one that draws rectangles around all the views.  I can see that the Netflix app just seems to have one main view, with no internal views.  But that doesn't necessarily mean it is a WebView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to inspect the UI of a running production app on a device, to see what widgets it uses and where they are located on-screen.