# How to do independently scrolling rows and columns (a la Netflix app) on Android in a WebView?

Tags: android, uiwebview, android-webview

In Netflix's Android app, there is a WebView that covers almost the entire app's area.  When you drag a row left to right, it will scroll only that row, and do so using nice inertial scrolling.  If you drag up and down, it will scroll the whole page up and down.

[image: netflix app on android]

I've managed to duplicate this functionality on iOS (in a uiWebView as well as in Safari proper), but not on Android.  On Android devices, anything I do is either painfully slow to scroll, or you have to be very careful scrolling vertically to start by touching in the background area between rows.  Neither of which are acceptable.  Obviously, I don't want to do the scrolling animation in javascript, as that will be too slow.

I know Netflix does it using a WebView, so....what is the trick they are using?

I have tried using the css properties (for the row div):

```
overflow-y: hidden;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling-x: touch
```

to no avail.

Comment: As far as I am aware, WebView is just a "portal" to a web page display, anything that goes inside it merely HTML, CSS and JavaScript, nothing Android dependent.

Comment: Well the inertial touch capabilities are implemented in iOS and Android differently.  For instance the "-webkit-overflow-scrolling-x: touch" is going to have no effect on a browser running on your desktop, but influences how it works in an Android or iOS app. There are lots of specific things they've done to make the browser work nicely on touch-based platforms -- the trick is knowing how to tap into them.

Comment: Have you considered maybe they are not using a WebView? Maybe it is actually an implemented XML layout?

Comment: It is done with a webview.  They say so much in their blog, as well as you can do various things to tell what is running. (for instance, see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115922/is-it-possible-to-tell-whether-a-compiled-android-app-is-using-a-webview )

Comment: If you want help in optimizing this, you'll need to post some code of a simple example that does not work fast enough.

Comment: TableLayout + ScrollView = voila!

Answer (score 3):

If you can't get the css Android compatible for your particular WebView, why not create server-side functionality that outputs only requested rows into seperate WebViews?

I would do the following:
* Query the web server to determine how many rows there are.
* Programmatically add the amount of rows that the web server says it has. For example, if the server reports that there are 5 rows, create 5 WebViews, each with their own URL params (ex: the first WebView would query `mydomain.com/wv?row=1`).
* Put each WebView row in a HorizontalScrollView, and put all HorizontalScrollViews in a VerticalScrollView.
* On URL change, go to a full-page WebView that displays the details of the clicked tile.
* On back pressed, close full page WebView and reload rows.

Not the cleanest of solutions, but should work fine.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  Scrolling won't work as hoped (where moving your finger in a mostly up-down direction move the overall view, and right-left will scroll the element in the web view. Regardless Netflix proves it can be done the way I need to do it.

Comment: To make it a bit better- put the same url for all of them, some url that will display a "loading" page for the specific row. then, on android list view "createView" method make the webview to preform a ajax request to fetch the specific row data. in this case the scrolling will be much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) in your HTML.
In the link you can find the source code, examples and javascript libs.
Also it has some useful callbacks.
 
I use it a lot when I'm working with WebViews.

Comment: Is there any way of doing independent horizontal and vertical?  I don't see any examples that show this.

Answer (score 0):

Netflix could have used custom gesture detection and have seen if the scroll was more horizontal then vertical or more vertical than horizontal, and then based on how far the scroll was, scrolled the webview horizontally or vertically